# Resize Table VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have table that ranges from A1:D1

I want to resize it from A1:DIncreasedRange where IncreasedRanged is a Value(Integer) found in cell G3. I have tried that following:

```
Sub ResizeList()
  Dim wrksht As Worksheet
  Dim objListObj As ListObject
  Dim IncreasedRange As Ingter

  Set wrksht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
  Set objListObj = wrksht.ListObjects("Table1")

  IncreasedRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, "G").Value
  MsgBox (IncreasedRange)

  objListObj.Resize Range("A1:(D+IncreasedRange)")
End Sub
```

If I try:

```
objListObj.Resize Range("A1:D15)")
```

The code works fine otherwise I get an error. Any ideas?
I have also tried:

```
 objListObj.Resize objListObj.Resize Range(IncreasedRange)
```

Comment: (1) Use `objListObj.Resize Range("A1:D" & IncreasedRange)` to append a variable value to an existing string. Otherwise the variable name would be recognized as part of the string. (2) Always use `Long` instead of `Integer`, Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle.

Comment: I got the following error when i tried that : Rum-time error '13' typ mismatch

Comment: Better to specify the sheet too: `objListObj.Resize wrksht.Range("A1:D" & IncreasedRange)`

Comment: Now i seem to be getting the following error when changing the value

" The range you have specified is invalid......" 

any ideas?

Comment: This is probably because `IncreasedRange` is `0` because `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, "G").Value` is empty or no valid number.

Comment: Yes you are correct! Thank you! Another question:

I'm trying to delete rows in a specifc range. I tried this: 

Range("A"&IncreasedRange ":D"&CurrentSize)).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft                                                                                              But it does not seem to work.

Comment: Because you missed a `&`, you need to connect all variable names and string parts like `Range("A" & IncreasedRange & ":D" & CurrentSize).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft`